# How do I find specific rows that throws an error when saving in Graphlab SFrame?

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, graphlab, sframe

I have a `SFrame` that looks like this with `sf.print_rows(10)`:

```
+--------------+---------------+-------+-------------------------------+
|   Dataset    |     Domain    | Score |             Sent1             |
+--------------+---------------+-------+-------------------------------+
| STS2012-gold | surprise.OnWN |  5.0  | render one language in ano... |
| STS2012-gold | surprise.OnWN |  3.25 | nations unified by shared ... |
| STS2012-gold | surprise.OnWN |  3.25 | convert into absorbable su... |
| STS2012-gold | surprise.OnWN |  4.0  | devote or adapt exclusivel... |
| STS2012-gold | surprise.OnWN |  3.25 | elevated wooden porch of a... |
| STS2012-gold | surprise.OnWN |  4.0  | either half of an archery bow |
| STS2012-gold | surprise.OnWN | 3.333 | a removable device that is... |
| STS2012-gold | surprise.OnWN |  4.75 |      restrict or confine      |
| STS2012-gold | surprise.OnWN |  0.5  |     orient, be positioned     |
| STS2012-gold | surprise.OnWN |  4.75 | Bring back to life, return... |
+--------------+---------------+-------+-------------------------------+
+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
|             Sent2             |        Sent1_tokenized        |
+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| restate (words) from one l... | [render, one, language, in... |
| a group of nations having ... | [nations, unified, by, sha... |
| soften or disintegrate by ... | [convert, into, absorbable... |
| devote oneself to a specia... | [devote, or, adapt, exclus... |
| a porch that resembles the... | [elevated, wooden, porch, ... |
| either of the two halves o... | [either, half, of, an, arc... |
| a supplementary part or ac... | [a, removable, device, tha... |
| place limits on (extent or... |    [restrict, or, confine]    |
|          be opposite.         |   [orient,, be, positioned]   |
|  cause to become alive again. | [Bring, back, to, life,, r... |
+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
+-------------------------------+-----------+-----------+----------------------+
|        Sent2_tokenized        | Sent1_len | Sent2_len | NGRAM-cosChar2ngrams |
+-------------------------------+-----------+-----------+----------------------+
| [restate, (words), from, o... |     6     |     8     |      0.82090085      |
| [a, group, of, nations, ha... |     8     |     7     |      0.53250804      |
| [soften, or, disintegrate,... |     11    |     11    |      0.43274232      |
| [devote, oneself, to, a, s... |     10    |     8     |      0.47759567      |
| [a, porch, that, resembles... |     6     |     9     |      0.38885689      |
| [either, of, the, two, hal... |     6     |     12    |      0.55555556      |
| [a, supplementary, part, o... |     10    |     5     |      0.44963552      |
| [place, limits, on, (exten... |     3     |     6     |      0.27124449      |
|        [be, opposite.]        |     3     |     2     |      0.43528575      |
| [cause, to, become, alive,... |     8     |     5     |      0.37047929      |
+-------------------------------+-----------+-----------+----------------------+
+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| NGRAM-cosChar3ngrams | NGRAM-cosChar4ngrams | NGRAM-cosChar5ngrams |
+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|      0.74964917      |      0.71490469      |      0.67925959      |
|      0.36701702      |      0.28941438      |      0.23635427      |
|      0.25899951      |      0.21053227      |      0.17058877      |
|      0.26248718      |      0.20518234      |      0.14285714      |
|      0.17107978      |      0.12049505      |      0.09320546      |
|      0.40754381      |      0.24715577      |      0.11547005      |
|      0.21997067      |      0.17554945      |      0.15450786      |
|      0.13284223      |      0.09284767      |       0.048795       |
|      0.31426968      |      0.17149859      |      0.09449112      |
|      0.0632772       |      0.03402069      |         0.0          |
+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+

[19097 rows x 134 columns]
```

But when I tried to save it into a csv with `sf.save('trainers.csv', format='csv')`, it throws an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-f82bcb3fa197> in <module>()
----> 1 sts.save('trainers.csv', format='csv')

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/graphlab/data_structures/sframe.pyc in save(self, filename, format)
   2924                 self.export_json(url)
   2925             else:
-> 2926                 raise ValueError("Unsupported format: {}".format(format))
   2927 
   2928     def export_csv(self, filename, delimiter=',', line_terminator='\n',

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/graphlab/cython/context.pyc in __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback)
     47             if not self.show_cython_trace:
     48                 # To hide cython trace, we re-raise from here
---> 49                 raise exc_type(exc_value)
     50             else:
     51                 # To show the full trace, we do nothing and let exception propagate

RuntimeError: Runtime Exception. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-5-e29b4d4eba06>", line 20, in <lambda>
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

I print the n no. of rows one at a time, e.g. `sf.print_rows(10)`, `sf.print_rows(100)` and at `sf.print_rows(129)`, it throws an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-13550768dbcd> in <module>()
----> 1 sts.print_rows(129)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/graphlab/data_structures/sframe.pyc in print_rows(self, num_rows, num_columns, max_column_width, max_row_width, output_file)
   2226         max_row_width = max(max_row_width, max_column_width + 1)
   2227 
-> 2228         printed_sf = self._imagecols_to_stringcols(num_rows)
   2229         row_of_tables = printed_sf.__get_pretty_tables__(wrap_text=False,
   2230                                                          max_rows_to_display=num_rows,

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/graphlab/data_structures/sframe.pyc in _imagecols_to_stringcols(self, num_rows)
   2250                 if t in image_column_names:
   2251                     printed_sf[t] = self[t].astype(str)
-> 2252         return printed_sf.head(num_rows)
   2253 
   2254     def __str_impl__(self, num_rows=10, footer=True):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/graphlab/data_structures/sframe.pyc in head(self, n)
   2454         tail, print_rows
   2455         """
-> 2456         return SFrame(_proxy=self.__proxy__.head(n))
   2457 
   2458     def to_dataframe(self):

graphlab/cython/cy_sframe.pyx in graphlab.cython.cy_sframe.UnitySFrameProxy.head()

graphlab/cython/cy_sframe.pyx in graphlab.cython.cy_sframe.UnitySFrameProxy.head()

RuntimeError: Runtime Exception. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-5-e29b4d4eba06>", line 20, in <lambda>
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

So I did a `sf.fillna(c, 0)`:

```
for c in sts.column_names():
    sts = sts.fillna(c, 0)
```

and it throws another error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-e63cf73308dd> in <module>()
      1 for c in sts.column_names():
----> 2     sts = sts.fillna(c, 0)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/graphlab/data_structures/sframe.pyc in fillna(self, column, value)
   5652             raise TypeError("Must give column name as a str")
   5653         ret = self[self.column_names()]
-> 5654         ret[column] = ret[column].fillna(value)
   5655         return ret
   5656 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/graphlab/data_structures/sarray.pyc in fillna(self, value)
   2439 
   2440         with cython_context():
-> 2441             return SArray(_proxy = self.__proxy__.fill_missing_values(value))
   2442 
   2443     def topk_index(self, topk=10, reverse=False):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/graphlab/cython/context.pyc in __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback)
     47             if not self.show_cython_trace:
     48                 # To hide cython trace, we re-raise from here
---> 49                 raise exc_type(exc_value)
     50             else:
     51                 # To show the full trace, we do nothing and let exception propagate

RuntimeError: Runtime Exception. Default value must be convertible to column type
```

**How do I find specific rows that throws an error when saving in Graphlab SFrame?**

And how do I fix this row? Can I just replace the problematic columns in the rows with `fillna()`? I can't really throw the rows away with `dropna()` since I need to keep track of the problematic rows.

But even with `dropna()`, I end up with:

```
sf.dropna()
sf.save('trainers.csv', format='csv')
```

**How do I find these rows that gives me Errors or ZeroDivisionErrors? And how to correct them or fill these columns with zeros?**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-f82bcb3fa197> in <module>()
----> 1 sts.save('trainers.csv', format='csv')

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/graphlab/data_structures/sframe.pyc in save(self, filename, format)
   2924                 self.export_json(url)
   2925             else:
-> 2926                 raise ValueError("Unsupported format: {}".format(format))
   2927 
   2928     def export_csv(self, filename, delimiter=',', line_terminator='\n',

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/graphlab/cython/context.pyc in __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback)
     47             if not self.show_cython_trace:
     48                 # To hide cython trace, we re-raise from here
---> 49                 raise exc_type(exc_value)
     50             else:
     51                 # To show the full trace, we do nothing and let exception propagate

RuntimeError: Runtime Exception. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-5-e29b4d4eba06>", line 20, in <lambda>
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Strangely, I cannot iterate through the SFrame, when I try to iterate through the SFrame with:

```
for i in sf:
    print i
```

It throws this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-d2d0035d7bbe> in <module>()
----> 1 for i in sts:
      2     print i

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/graphlab/data_structures/sframe.pyc in generator()
   3712         def generator():
   3713             elems_at_a_time = 262144
-> 3714             self.__proxy__.begin_iterator()
   3715             ret = self.__proxy__.iterator_get_next(elems_at_a_time)
   3716             column_names = self.column_names()

graphlab/cython/cy_sframe.pyx in graphlab.cython.cy_sframe.UnitySFrameProxy.begin_iterator()

graphlab/cython/cy_sframe.pyx in graphlab.cython.cy_sframe.UnitySFrameProxy.begin_iterator()

RuntimeError: Runtime Exception. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-5-e29b4d4eba06>", line 10, in <lambda>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

It gets stranger, I couldn't retrieve a specific row with `sf[num]` but I can do a sub-SFrame and then retrieve that particular `num` row. So this:

```
print sf[25]
```

breaks and throws:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-6bc8898704c0> in <module>()
----> 1 print sts[25]

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/graphlab/data_structures/sframe.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
   3595             ub = min(sf_len, lb + block_size)
   3596 
-> 3597             val_list = list(SFrame(_proxy = self.__proxy__.copy_range(lb, 1, ub)))
   3598             self._cache["getitem_cache"] = (lb, ub, val_list)
   3599             return val_list[key - lb]

graphlab/cython/cy_sframe.pyx in graphlab.cython.cy_sframe.UnitySFrameProxy.copy_range()

graphlab/cython/cy_sframe.pyx in graphlab.cython.cy_sframe.UnitySFrameProxy.copy_range()

RuntimeError: Runtime Exception. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-5-e29b4d4eba06>", line 10, in <lambda>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

But when I try to extract a subset and then print, it works. The code below retrieves the 25th element that was previously error-throwing with the code above:

```
x =  sf[:30]
print x[25]
```

**Is there a reason for why the previous code with `sf[25]` throws a `NoneType`?** `sf[0]` to `sf[24]` works but anything above 25 didn't.

Appparently, iterating the SFrame this way and dumping it out as str sorta works:

```
fout = open('superbad.txt', 'w')
sflen = len(sf)
i = 0
while i < sflen:
    m = i+100 if i+100 < sflen else sflen
    x = sf[i:m]
    for j in x:
        fout.write(str(j) +'\n\n')
```

It's rather strange. **Why is that iterating in chunks and dumping to string works?**

Comment: get row one-by-one and save it and you find row with problem.

Comment: It can't be iterated for some strange reason.

Comment: Found the problem, there was  `None` column in several rows that ends up into error when I tried to do some counts of `eval('None')`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the division by zero error that you have when running an apply (somewhere above the save)

```
RuntimeError: Runtime Exception. Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<ipython-input-5-e29b4d4eba06>", line 20, in <lambda>
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

This happens because of lazy evaluation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation). As an example, suppose I start with an SFrame with a single column

```
sf = gl.SFrame({'x': range(10000, -1, -1)})
sf['x'].apply(lambda x: 1.0/x)
```

At this point of time, the last row of the SFrame contains a `1.0/0` value which is an error, but this has not been evaluated yet. The `save` method triggers a materialization i.e an actual computation of all the rows in the data which then causes the error to happen. You can trigger this process using a call to `__materialize__`

```
sf.__materialize__()
```

which causes the following error to occur.

```
RuntimeError: Runtime Exception. Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<ipython-input-55-5af90e232e2d>", line 1, in <lambda>
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

Lazy evaluation and query planning is really important as a performance optimization and is one of the reasons why the SFrame is fast and scalable. Unfortunately, tracing errors is one of the annoyances of it, but you do get used to it once you are aware of how it works.

The `head()` function does not trigger a full materialization so you can execute it on as many rows as you want until you find the error.

Comment: actually that's part of the problem. the root of the problem comes from somewhere else =) https://github.com/dato-code/SFrame/issues/127